# Chrome DevTools Approve Network Requests before executing

Tags: api, google-chrome, http, devtools

I'm looking for a way in Chrome DevTools (or any equivalent) to control the HTTP requests done by my web application:

**I want to approve HTTP requests before executing, or let them fail in an unexpected way (give it status 500 or something).**

USAGE *EXAMPLE*: Testing unexpected behavior

Does anyone know a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions to achieve this goal on the client side:

1. Use the Request-Blocking panel from the Drawer (Open Chrome DevTools -> Esc -> '...' -> Request blocking
   [image]
   This is completely out-of-the-box and works for most "offline-first" use cases.
2. Use a service worker. They are basically a way to proxy requests and respond individually (e.g. by responding with a 500-er). You might want to enable/disable such a debugging-feature by using Chrome Devtools Snippets (Open Chrome DevTools -> Sources -> Snippets) as you don't want your requests to fail all the time :)

First you need to register your serviceworker like this:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/path-to-service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
    // registration successful
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // registration failed
  });
}
```

Afterwards reload the browser (or install your service-worker in the DevTools -> Application -> Service Workers) so that your service-worker.js is active, may listen to the 'fetch' event and proxy the requests for this domain like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // this will set a breakpoint in chrome devtools, allowing you to manually edit the response
  debugger; 
  // alternatively you could reponse with an error response like this:
  event.respondWith(
    new Response(null, {
      status: 500
    })
  );
});
```

Sidenote: Due to security restrictions in the browser serviceworkers only work over https and on localhost.

Further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Comment: Never heard of the request blocking feature before. This comes closest to what I was looking for. 
Serviceworker bit overkill :)  But it gave me the idea to create a axios interceptor which prompts on every request for approval or denial :)
Thnx!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) Chrome extension to Redirect, Cancel, Block, Modify headers,... of the requests.

[image]

To approve requests before executing e.g. for AJAX requests create a redirect rule and point it to a static JSON file or another script.

To block a request use cancel request feature and set a custom pattern.

Comment: Nice extension! Certainly contains the functionality meeting my needs. Reason I've accepted MattDiMu's answer instead of yours is because it doesn't require installation of extension to do request blocking.

Comment: @MatsdeSwart It's good to know if your use case is solved using Chrome Dev Tools feature. Requestly is much more sophisticated in terms of enabling/disabling the rule. You can mark your rule as favorite and quickly toggle from the popup. Requestly also tells you when your rule is executed just in case you forget after setting up the rule.